# Ability to move more than one image with 'touches'

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    basketView.center = CGPointMake(point.x, point.y);


}
```

I currently have this code that works to allow the user to move an image around with their finger. However, if I wanted to add multiple moveable images to the screen (say I also wanted to be able to move UIImages basketView2 and basketView3), how would I alter the code to allow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to modify your code as below

```
UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
UIImageView *currentView=(UIImageView *)touch.view;
currentView.center = CGPointMake(point.x, point.y);
```

Comment: Hmm, that's dragging the entire screen (background) and everything in it around

Comment: will you please check that your uiimageview's UserInteraction is enabled ? if yes then you can set tag 1,2.. to your views and before setting center position check whether currentView.tag >0 .

Comment: Ok, I set the tag like this: basketView.tag = 1;. Then I put this:     if (currentView.tag > 0)
        currentView.center = CGPointMake(point.x, point.y);. But the image won't move

Comment: then try for UIPanGestureRecognizer ,add this gesture on ur image views or you can take help of Apple documentation on UIPanGestureRecognizer,source code "Touches" is doing same thing what is looking for .[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435)